# [jsdoc]: @type{Object} does not hint properties

Tags: javascript, types, jsdoc

```
const test = {};

test.test1 = {};

test.test2 = [];
```

[fine working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT4K0.png)

```
/**
 * @type {Object}
 */
const test = {};

test.test1 = {};

test.test2 = [];
```

[bad working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SzMk.png)

After i declare type of test variable is Object that it doesn't show hint test1 & test2 properties

i try:

```
/**
 * @type {Object<string, any>}
 */
const test = {};

test.test1 = {};

test.test2 = [];
```

[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJo3A.png)

I want to declare type of test variable is Object and it will be hint test1 & test2 properties. Help me.